# It's possible to display the coordinates of vessels in Map?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I need your help please, first i don't speak English very good.

Secondly, about my problem i don't know if it's possible to get the coordinates of vessels and show them in the Map ?!

Thirdly, i develop an app with Ionic Framework about vessels and i want to display a map that contains the coordinates of vessels, it's easy but to get the coordinates that is my problem.

Thank you for help.

Comment: what do you mean by vessels? You could put markers on Google maps as long has you have GPS coordinates/valid address

Comment: coordinates are coordinates .. if these are from vessell, car or a simple marker is the same .. if you have  the coordinates you can show on a  google maps .. .. what's the problem .. the sea ? .. is not a problem ?

Comment: doge1ord : vessels i mean ships
 no scaisEdge i don't have the coordinates it's the problem, i search an API for example to get this coordinates :) if you have an idea 
thank you all

Comment: I'm not familiar on Ionic Framework so I can't help you with coding implementation. But you may want to read about FCM and [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/geolocation). You may use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to trigger a sending of coordinates to the server and Google Maps to load the coordinates and plot it.

Comment: Also try reading about [GeoFire](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/06/geofire-20.html), uses the Firebase Realtime Database for data storage, allowing query results to be updated in realtime as they change. See [geofire github](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/tree/master/examples) to check different uses of geofire samples.